# how to align lists of words using biopython pairwise2

Tags: biopython

When I run the script below, output is getting split into single chars. Any idea why? It looks like the second argument gets split into single chars.

I am trying to align the word sequences.

I will have many words hence cannot map them to letters only.

```python
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.pairwise2 import format_alignment


fruits = ["orange","pear", "apple","pear","orange"]
fruits1 = ["pear","apple"]


from Bio import pairwise2
alignments = pairwise2.align.localms(fruits,fruits1,2,-1,-0.5,-0.1, gap_char=["-"])

for a in alignments: 
    print(format_alignment(*a))
```

Output:

```
['orange', 'r', 'a', 'e', 'p', 'e', 'l', 'p', 'p', 'a', 'pear', 'orange']
 |||||||||
['-', 'r', 'a', 'e', 'p', 'e', 'l', 'p', 'p', 'a', '-', '-']
  Score=4
```

Comment: Sorry, in principle your example should work. ```pairwise2``` accepts lists as input. Obviously, I broke something during the last update of ```pairwise2```. If you have access to Biopython 1.67, can you try it there?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a list to localms which expects a `string` or a `Seq` object, also `gap_char` should be a string not a list.

Try the following snippet:

```
import Bio.pairwise2 as pairwise2
fruits = ["orange", "pear", "apple", "pear", "orange"]
fruits1 = ["pear", "apple"]
for f0 in fruits:
    for f1 in fruits1:
        print('Aligning {0} and {1}'.format(f0, f1))
        alignments = pairwise2.align.localms(f0, f1, 2, -1, -0.5, -0.1, gap_char="-")
        for a in alignments: 
            print(pairwise2.format_alignment(*a))
```

**Output**

> ```
> Aligning orange and pear
> orange
>   |
> pear--
>   Score=2
>
> Aligning orange and apple
> orange
>      |
> -apple
>   Score=2
>
> orange-
>   |
> --apple
>   Score=2
>
> Aligning pear and pear
> pear
> ||||
> pear
>   Score=8
> ```
>
> [...]

Comment: No, ```pairwise2``` should also accept lists. The reason is that you can then use sequences with contain symbols with more than one letter. This may be helpful if you have modified bases or amino acids, like in this SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142371/nucleotides-separator-in-the-pairwise-sequence-alignment-bio-python/36158674#36158674). Unfortunately, this functionality is broken in Biopython 1.68 and 1.69.

Comment: @Markus: Thanks for the clarification! It seems I was using one of the BioPython versions you were mentioning.